# Socket hang up error in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function that is triggered by a Pub / Sub event. It uses [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) to make multiple GET requests from an API I use for my data.

It works when running locally in the Cloud Functions Emulator, however in production I keep getting this error:

```
{ RequestError: Error: socket hang up
    at new RequestError (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:346:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Error: socket hang up',
  cause: 
   { Error: socket hang up
       at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:254:15)
       at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:346:23)
       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' },
  error: 
   { Error: socket hang up
       at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:254:15)
       at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:346:23)
       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' },
  options: 
   { method: 'GET',
     uri: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=BTC&start=0',
     json: true,
     callback: [Function: RP$callback],
     transform: undefined,
     simple: true,
     resolveWithFullResponse: false,
     transform2xxOnly: false },
  response: undefined }
```

Any idea why I get this socket hang up error when my Cloud Function runs?

**Edit:** Here is what my cloud function code looks like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var reqprom = require('request-promise');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.minutely_tick =
  functions.pubsub.topic('minutely-tick').onPublish((event) => {
    console.log('This job runs every 5 minutes!');
    getAllData()
      .then((dataArray) => {
        const ref = admin.database().ref(`myData/`);
        ref.set(dataArray);
        return console.log('dataArray length:', dataArray.length);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return console.log('Caught error: ', error);
      });
  });

function getAllData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var promises = [];
    var startInt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      const options = {
        method: GET,
        uri: myUrlString,
        json: true
      }
      promises.push(reqprom(options));
      startInt += 100;
    }

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((dict) => {
        var array = valuesFromDict(dict);
        return resolve(array);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return reject(error);
      });
  });

}

function valuesFromDict(dict) {
  var values = Object.keys(dict).map((key) => {
    return dict[key];
  });
  return values;
}
```

In summary, the function makes multiple API calls in a loop. And via promises I wait for all of them to complete. And then format that data into an array that I set to a Firebase Database reference.

Comment: What payment plan is your Firebase project on?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I am on Blaze

Comment: Please edit you question to show the actual code that's generating this error.

Comment: It's preferred that you provide the MCVE included in the question itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson Okay, I've pasted the code into the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning the final promise from your promise chain.  Cloud Functions requires that you return a promise that resolves only when all of the async work is complete in your function.

```
return getAllData().then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization, but that is not the root of the problem because I still get keep getting the error, even when returning the final promise as suggested. Also, from the Emulator the function has been successful regardless of returning the promise

Comment: This is not an optimization.  It's a requirement.  Cloud Functions will clamp down resources on your function and forcefully terminate if it doesn't return a promise that resolves only after all the work is done.  The emulator doesn't do this.

Comment: It is now working since making that change - I guess I had to wait a bit for the deployment to finalize because it wasn't working just after deploying. D'oh! Thanks again, @DougStevenson!

Comment: @DougStevenson just stumbled across this 5.5 years later and it solved my issue after much confusion with an identical (working) HTTP function vs a broken pubsub / scheduled function - apparently what you described is the main difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i had a content filter in my computer, when i removed it the problem solved